# How can i process same URL with different parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I faced some problems when I created some REST-API.

I want some API has different params.

For examples:

```
path?include="stack"
```

```
path?exclude="overflow"
```

I thought two ways.

- First: Create API can receive all params and process in the controller.

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity getByFilter(@RequestParam @Nullable final String exclude,
                                  @RequestParam @Nullable final String include){
 // any process to distinguish. 
}
```

- Second: Create several API can receive one param.

```
@GetMapping(params = "include")
public ResponseEntity getByInclude(@RequestParam final String include){
// do anything
}

@GetMapping(params = "exclude")
public ResponseEntity getByInclude(@RequestParam final String exclude){
// do anything
}
```

But both have problems.

- First: Logic will have increased by params.
- Second: SwaggerDocument I used for SpringBoot cannot support the same path, different params. If I use 'enableUrlTemplating', my teams will manage SwaggerDocument manually.

How can I solve these problems?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Go for the first approach, you'd need validation that only one parameter is passed though

Comment: Why not make 2 distinct urls? For example the first one could be `/path/include?type="stack"`, while the second one can be `/path/exclude?type="overflow"`.

Comment: @DimitarSpasovski I want to get 'path' resource, not exclude or include.

Comment: @choihyunjin Do you want only controller to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the first of your proposals, define your both @RequestParam and in the code, first thing, check that only one parameter is defined.

Then regarding the Swagger documentation, you could add:

- For each parameter, a description like this `@ApiParam(value = "Use this parameter to exclude some resources")`
- For the endpoint, a `@ApiOperation(value = "Endpoint name", notes = "Here you can put the description of the behavior you are expecting, write here if the parameters are to be used at the same time, are mutually exclusive, if you have to set always one...", response = YourResponseDTO.class)`

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: thank you for your reply , but i know that ways. i want to other solutions that can solve my problems that i faced.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with only one controller. Write controller like

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity getByFilter(@RequestParam(value="exclude", required=false) String exclude,@RequestParam(value="include", required= flase)String include){
 // any process to distinguish. 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i already write this way in my question.

Comment: @choihyunjin That's good! You can also try this way. Perhaps this is also another way that can help you in the future! Happy coding!